# Issue with jqGrid with dynamic colModel while editing rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using a jqGrid as a generic table-like editable control. My goal is to have pairs of `name -> value` in a table where the `value`s are editables.

Everything goes well as long as I don't mess up with the `colModel`: if I have a table with mixed value types I'm *forced* to change the `colModel` in order to match it with the value being edited. For example, in a table with 3 values: `Name`, `Surname`, `Married?`, the last one is of type `checkbox` while the other ones are of the type `string`.

After editing the field `Married?`, if we click on the other fields their content changes to `Yes:No` while  in edit mode, the string `Yes:No` is the one used by the checkbox field; anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?:

```
var data =
[
    {name:"Name", value:"John"},
    {name:"Surname", value:"Doe"},
    {name:"Married", value:"No"}
];
var currentrow = 0;

function edit(id)
{
    if (id && id !== currentrow)
    {
        var table = jQuery("#grid");

        function colProp(id)
        {
            switch (id)
            {
                case "1":
                case "2":
                return { editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: {} };

                case "3":
                return { editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: {value: 'Yes:No'} };
            }
        }

        table.jqGrid('restoreRow', currentrow);
        table.setColProp('value', colProp(id));
        table.jqGrid('editRow', id, true,
             undefined, undefined, 'clientArray');

        currentrow = id;
    }
}

$("#grid").jqGrid
({
    datatype: "local",
    data: data,
    colNames: ['Name', 'Value'],
    colModel:
    [
        { name: 'name' },
        { name: 'value' }
    ],
    onSelectRow: edit
});
```

At first, I was thinking that after editing a field with `edittype: checkbox` the next fields being editet *inherits* the previous `edittype`, that's why I set the `editoptions` to an empty object while editing text fields, but it didn't work.

I've pasted the [code into a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9KHY/) in order to share a working example of my issue.

PS: Maybe jqGrid isn't the best choice to achieve my goal, but I'm forced to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the problem you can just use

```
editoptions: {value: null}
```

to remove `value` property. The corresponding demo inclusive some other minimal modifications you will find here: http://jsfiddle.net/y9KHY/2/.

The corresponding code is

```
var data =  [
        {id: "10", name:"Name", value:"John", edittype: "text"},
        {id: "20", name:"Surname", value:"Doe", edittype: "text"},
        {id: "30", name:"Married", value:"No", edittype: "checkbox"}
    ],
    currentrow = 0;

function edit(id) {
    var table = jQuery(this),
        item = table.jqGrid("getLocalRow", id);

    function colProp(id) {
        switch (item.edittype) {
            case "checkbox":
                return { editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: {value: 'Yes:No'} };
            default:
                return { editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: {value: null} };
        }
    }

    if (id && id !== currentrow) {
        table.jqGrid('restoreRow', currentrow);
        table.setColProp('value', colProp(id));
        table.jqGrid('editRow', id, true);

        currentrow = id;
    }
}

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: data,
    colNames: ['Name', 'Value'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'name' },
        { name: 'value', editable: true }
    ],
    rowNum: 10000,
    autoencode: true,
    gridview: true,
    height: "auto",
    editurl: "clientArray",
    onSelectRow: edit
});
```